# TransmogrifAI : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, scala, transmogrifai

I am trying to run this [project](https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI#quick-start-and-documentation) , After following instructions what they have provided :

- Install Java 1.8
- Get Spark 2.2.x: Download, unzip it and then set an environment
  variable: export SPARK_HOME=
- Clone the TransmogrifAI repo: git clone
  https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI.git
- Build the project: cd TransmogrifAI && ./gradlew compileTestScala
  installDist

Till yet i am getting this message:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :scalaStyle
Found 0 warnings
Found 0 errors

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43s
8 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

After that i want to try one of their model which is here:

https://docs.transmogrif.ai/en/stable/examples/Titanic-Binary-Classification.html

But during running command :

```
cd helloworld
./gradlew compileTestScala installDist
./gradlew -q sparkSubmit -Dmain=com.salesforce.hw.OpTitanicSimple -Dargs="\
`pwd`/src/main/resources/TitanicDataset/TitanicPassengersTrainData.csv"
```

I am getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sparkSubmit'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/bin/spark-submit''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I tried to find out but couldn't get any idea about this , How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/bin/spark-submit''

The "null" part in "null/bin/spark-submit" shows that somehow  "SPARK_HOME" location is not set. 
You mentioned about setting the environment variable in second step of installation.

So could you check if SPARK_HOME environment variable is set correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `SPARK_HOME` correctly pointing to the folder where you extracted Spark.
E.g. `export SPARK_HOME="~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7"`